# cocos2d-x use create() method in update method

Tags: cocos2d-x

i use cocos2d-x for my game.
i have some question about cocos2d-x create method.

i always use create() method to create new Animation , Animate , RepeatForever Object when the game character needs to change the animation in Update Method

but i think this is not good because if i create new Animation, Animate , RepeatForever Object to change my game character's anitation like below
(below code is just a part of Update method )

```
auto anim = cocos2d::Animation::create();
anim->setDelayPerUnit(0.3);

anim->addSpriteFrameWithFile("./Hero/walk1_0.png");

anim->addSpriteFrameWithFile("./Hero/walk1_1.png");


anim->addSpriteFrameWithFile("./Hero/walk1_2.png");

anim->addSpriteFrameWithFile("./Hero/walk1_3.png");

auto animation = cocos2d::Animate::create(anim);

m_pBasicSprite->runAction(animation);
```

when the game character change the animation frequently, then it will cause create too many cocos object. so how should i gonna do?

p.s

i use class memeber variable for save that Object's instead of create new cocos animation object for each loop in update method,
but it cause error the error said "expression _referenceCount > 0"

p.s2

i'm sorry about my terrible english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside ClassName.h:

```
CCAction* _aniRun;
void createAnimation();
```

Inside ClassName.cpp:

```
// create a function
void ClassName::createAnimation()
{
    // run ani
    CCAnimation* animation=CCAnimation::create();
    animation->setDelayPerUnit(0.05f);
    for (int i=0; i<1; i++)
    {
        char str[50];
        sprintf(str,"game/bird/run%d.png", i);
        animation->addSpriteFrameWithFileName(str);
    }
    _aniRun = CCRepeatForever::create(CCAnimate::create(animation));
    _aniRun->retain();
}
```

Now wherever you want to play animation just call

```
player->runAction(aniRun);
```

Don't forget to release `_aniRun` inside destructor:

```
CC_SAFE_RELEASE(_aniRun);
```

Comment: excuse me, may i ask more question about cocos node object?

what is retain() method? i heard that retain() and release() is controlling method about cocos node object's reference count.

but, when the cocos object ref count will increase or decrease?

can you give me some ideas about retain() and release() ?
when i call retain and release()?

thank you so much

Comment: @HelloWorld  i have added a answer it will help you.. not so much clear because i am also new ..

Answer (score 1):

I am also new for cocos2d-x .i do not have full command over it .. i have basic idea about retain() and release().

in cocos 2dx , there is a  AutoreleasePool -- which takes care of referancecount , when you call object->autorelease() , this object
will be added to this autoreleasepool. this pool will help you to ratain the object for the lifetime of current frame.

There are 4 functions of Ref, the meanings are

```
retain: add reference count by 1

release: minus reference count by 1

autorelease: put the object in to AutoReleasePool, which means that cocos2d-x will invoke release automatically at the end of this frame

getReferenceCount: as the meaning of the function, it will retain the reference count of this object
```

cocos2dx has an autorelease pool which drains the objects which have retain count=0 which is a variable to keep in check the scope of the cocos2dx object.

Now when you create new object using the create method it is already added to the autorelease pool and you don't need to release it or delete it anywhere .

But when you create new object using 'new' you definitely need to release it in its destructor or after its use is over.

when your object is added to the autorelease pool but you need it somewhere else you could just retain it , this increments its retain count by one and then you have to manually release it after its use is over.

Whenever you add child your object it is retained automatically but you don't need to release it rather you remove it from the parent.

There are simple rules with retain() and autorelease():

1. everything I create with new are mine and I’m responsible for deleting them from memory
2. everything returned using a create()-method is autoreleased and will be released when the CURRENT METHOD ENDS. If the retainCount is zero, they will be purged from memory. When I need them in an instance variable I have to retain them.
3. everything I retain I’ll have to release   this from memory.

See this retain/release thing as a reference counter. If the counter is down to zero the object will be deleted.